# How to peek into ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator buffer in Spring Websocket?

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket

Class  ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator in Spring Websocket contains

```
private final Queue<WebSocketMessage<?>> buffer = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
```

that represent bunch of messages that for a queue to be sent towards clients. If the field

```
private final int bufferSizeLimit;
```

exceeded, an exception is thrown and client is disconnected. I would like to be able to check this buffer size from my application in order to execute flow control and be able to prevent buffer overflow.

How I could possibly peek into this buffer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use method [getBufferSize](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/handler/ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.html#getBufferSize--) to obtain summary size of already added messages.